# How to insert node in adjacency list in C?

Tags: c, nodes, adjacency-list

I want to create an `adjacency list` which includes three `struct` as below shown. Now I am working on insertion method which just insert the first node in each row. However, when I try to print all row with first node, it prints nothing. In `int main()`, when I input "InsertNode" following by id and name, it call will the method and insert the node. I am quite sure that my `print` and `main` method are correct. Which part of my insert method go wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node{
    char name[100];
    int id;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
typedef struct Row{
    Node *header;
    struct Row *next;
} Row;
typedef struct{
    Row *header;
} Adj_List;


void InsertNode(Adj_List *g, int x, char n[]){
    Row *p = g->header;
    Node *p_Node;
    if(p=NULL){
        p_Node=new Node;
        p_Node=p->header;
        p_Node->id=x;
        strcpy(p_Node->name,n);
        p_Node->next=NULL;
        p->next=NULL;
    }else{
        while (p!=NULL){
            p_Node=p->header;
            if(strcmp(p_Node->name,n)==0){
                printf("NodeExist\n");
            }else if(p=NULL){
                p_Node=new Node;
                p_Node=p->header;
                p_Node->id=x;
                strcpy(p_Node->name,n);
                p_Node->next=NULL;
                p->next=NULL;
            }else{
                p=p->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void PrintAdjacencyList(Adj_List *g){
    Row *p=g->header;
    while (p!=NULL){
        Node *p_Node=p->header;
        printf("%s",p_Node->name);
        p_Node=p_Node->next;
        int flag=0;
        while(p_Node!=NULL){
            if (!flag){
                printf(": %s",p_Node->name);
                flag=1;
            }
            else
                printf(" - %s",p_Node->name);
                p_Node=p_Node->next;
            }
        printf("\n");
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    char command[100];
    Adj_List g;
    g.header=NULL;

    while (scanf("%s",command)){
        if (strcmp(command, "insert")==0){
            int x;
            char name[100];
            scanf("%d %s\n",&x, name);
            InsertNode( &g, x, name);
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "Print")==0){
            PrintAdjacencyList( &g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then test it and put it in your question. A mcve has `#include`s and a `main()`.

Comment: Looks like you never set `g->header`

Comment: `if(p=NULL){` --> `if(p==NULL){`

Comment: What are your compiler warning flags? You should get a warning mentioning you Bluepixy's comment.

Comment: the header refers to row's header which set in adj_list struct @kaylum

Comment: @BLUEPIXY after i changed to `if(p==NULL) ` , the compiler gives error and exits when i insert second node of second row.

Comment: @jdarthenay there are no warning flags before and after i correct the code as Bluepixy' comment

Comment: No warning flags? Then put them! Use **at least** `-Wall` when compiling, and I also recommend `-Wextra`. And add `-Werror`, because compiling bad code is bad idea.

Comment: Is that C or C++? `new` is C++ code and you should not use those `#include`s in a C++ program.

Comment: @WILLIAM `p_Node=p->header;` and `p->next=NULL;` are bad(`p->`) if `p==NULL`. you need make `Row` object and `p_Node` set to it and write back to  `g->header`.